# How to get progressbar working?

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am just starting out with angular and trying to create a progressbar with a directive:

```
var module = angular.module("app", []);
module.directive("progressbar", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element) {

            //debugger;
            for (var i = 0; i<100;i++) {
                console.log(i);
                element.css("width", i / 100 + "%");
            }

        }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" progressbar></div>
</div>
```

It enters the loop but nothing is displaying? This is a link to a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dingen2010/fg229svz/23/

Comment: It already applying style="width: 0.99%;". If you replace element.css("width", i / 100 + "%"); with element.css("width", i+ "%");  than you will see the width.

Comment: This link should help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20862165/3538394

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** of all, your `progress-bar` doesn't have height, so its height is `0px`. Please set some height.

**Secondly**, your progress should be `(i+1)` not `(i/100)`, since width is from `0%` to `100%`. Otherwise, `width` would be from `0.01%` to `0.99%`.

**Thirdly**, I think you misunderstand what `link` is for. `link` must be completed before any directive is rendered, so you won't see `progress-bar` growing animation. The app will waits for loop inside `link` to finish before displaying.

What you need to do is `$watch` some directive attribute for loading progress. There are many way to implement this, this is just one of the way:

http://jsfiddle.net/dmqnqkkn/2/