# real time progress bar in angularJs with jquery

Tags: angularjs

I opened link : [Change bootstrap progress-bar width from angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861313/change-bootstrap-progress-bar-width-from-angularjs)

I'm trying to show progress-bar with percent while uploading the file, it should show actual uploading time in AngularJS.

Comment: What is th issue here. What have you tried till now ?

Comment: 1. I have $scope.total = data.file.size                                                         2. what is  $scope.threshold value,                      so here defined  $scope.getPercentage() is not returning right value

Comment: It is just a value based on which he is calculating the percentage. you can use any value there. Just make sure end result is less then 100.

Comment: So how i should calculate the actual values and this values should update progress-bar div

Comment: You need to find the actual values based on the total size to be uploaded and the amount of size uploaded.

Comment: yes, how it will do in jquery?

Comment: That is something which you need to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

forget jQuery - it doesn't always play nicely with Angular since jQuery may update the DOM outside the Angular domain and then you have to start worrying about binding data to the view (which is done naturally with angular modules).

I recommend using ng-file-upload which provides progress information during upload.

I would also recommend using ui-bootstrap which has a nice progress bar to use. Just update the progress bar % info with the information given to you by ng-file-upload.

Hope this helps. Heres how to get % progress

```
$scope.upload = function (file) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'upload/url',
        data: {file: file, 'username': $scope.username}
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
    };
```

Comment: Is image-select and ng-file-upload same in angularJS ? if not please suggest more in ng-file-upload in angularJS

Comment: ng-file-upload allows the upload of multiple files - they can be image files ... see the docs at https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: not finding clear view about upload file with real time progress bar in angularJS

Comment: Actually I have controller in angular, here i'm not able to get uploaded file size and remaining file size to upload. If have these both, then I'm able to find percent for progress-bar. here in jquery  (evt or event ) is not working

Comment: yes with jquery you will have binding difficulty - use ng-file-upload - i have added the code you need to my answer

Comment: I downloaded above zip file, in separate, this application running fine. There are a lot of js and css files used in above. But I have to plug-in in my existing project. what specific file I need to add in plug-in in my existing application

Comment: In above coding "evt" throwing exeption

Comment: what is value of evt? is it ever 0? divide by zero is error - you need to do an IF statement to make sure it is not 0

Comment: saying "evt" is not defined and conflict with angular.js