# How to show upload indicator during upload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm using ng-file-upload to upload an image, but can't find the way to add upload animation instead of image during upload process. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: what have you tried? you can easily do it by intercepting the http calls. refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838708/implementing-loading-spinner-using-httpinterceptor-and-angularjs-1-1-5)..

Comment: The demo page and most examples have the progress indicator if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using something like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress) or some other css library that has a progress bar component. They will have these animations built in and are fairly easy to set up. (See the link above for bootstrap's progress bar).

You can find a similar stack overflow post about angularjs and bootstrap progress bars [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861313/change-bootstrap-progress-bar-width-from-angularjs).

[Change bootstrap progress-bar width from angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861313/change-bootstrap-progress-bar-width-from-angularjs)