# How to apply an API figure to Bootstrap progress bar in Angular 6?

Tags: angular6, progress-bar, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm new to Angular 6 and I've just managed to achieve calling API's into table rows

```
<tr *ngFor="let stats of stats$">
  {{ stats.StoragePercentage }}%
</tr>
```

This calls percentage figures into tables and I now want to add bootstrap progress bars alongside these figures to highlight this. I came across this Stack Overflow question: [Change bootstrap progress-bar width from angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861313/change-bootstrap-progress-bar-width-from-angularjs) and tried the answers provided there with no luck. To me, what I have right now, that still doesn't work is the following:

```
<tr *ngFor="let stats of stats$">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" 
      role="progressbar"
      ng-style="width: {{ stats.StoragePercentage }}"
      aria-valuenow="{{ stats.StoragePercentage }}"
      aria-valuemax="100">
        {{ stats.StoragePercentage }}%
    </div>
  </div>
</tr>
```

The errors I get are:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you are not doing correctly is using `ng-style` which is AngularJS directive and not for Angular 2+. Try the below:

```
<tr *ngFor="let stats of stats$">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" 
      role="progressbar"
      [ngStyle]="{'width': stats.StoragePercentage + '%'}"
      aria-valuenow="{{ stats.StoragePercentage }}"
      aria-valuemax="100">
        {{ stats.StoragePercentage }}%
    </div>
  </div>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message says, the ng-style property is a isn't a know property.

Please see [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

```js
<tr *ngFor="let stats of stats$">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" 
      role="progressbar"
      [ngStyle]="width: {{ stats.StoragePercentage }}"
      aria-valuenow="{{ stats.StoragePercentage }}"
      aria-valuemax="100">
        {{ stats.StoragePercentage }}%
    </div>
  </div>
</tr>
```

Comment: I get the error: Can't bind to 'ng-style' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("progress-bar" role="progressbar" [ERROR ->][ng-style]="width: {{stats.StoragePercentage}}"